# Método power e tratamento de exceções

Tags: java, exceção

Devo resolver o seguinte exercício mas estou com algumas duvidas:

Criar uma classe que tenha apenas um método `power`, que recebe 2 números e calcula o numero 1 elevado ao numero 2.

Esse processo deve conter uma exceção caso algum dos números lançados seja negativo.

Até o momento fiz o seguinte código, mas queria confirmar se ele esta escrito da melhor forma possível e como devo fazer a exceção.

```
public class Calculadora
{
    public static int power(int n, int p) {
        return (int)Math.pow(n, p);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(power(10,2));
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(a < 0 || b < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Alguma mensagem...");`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Está tudo certo, só falta lançar a exceção antes de executar o cálculo. Normalmente quando o requisito é validar os parâmetros a primeira coisa que se faz é usar um ou mais `if`s com a verificação e procede o lançamento da exceção terminando a execução do método sem executar mais nada.

```
import java.lang.*;

class Calculadora {
    public static int power(int n, int p) {
        if (n < 0 || p < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("n ou p"); //poderia sofisticar a mensagem.
        return (int)Math.pow(n, p);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(power(10, 2));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/mV2vtI). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/sspmbsbr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Exception/Pow.java).

Eventualmente algum método pode ser mais interessante sair por erro de outra forma, mas não é caso, não só pelo requisito da pergunta, mas também porque outra forma poderia ser ambígua ou exigiria uma mudança de tipo e complicação desnecessária para o caso. Não é o jeito Java de fazer.

Existem outras técnicas possíveis, mas esta é adequada à pergunta.

Comment: Se rendeu ao lançamento de exceções? :p Eu retornaria -1 quando o valor fosse invalido, para não lançar exceção, seguindo uma recomendação sua de outra pergunta.

Comment: Funcionou, só não entendi porque eu adiciono o throw antes de passar os paramentos (10 e 2) nesse caso.

Comment: @RafaelAugusto se os valores não atenderem  a condição do if, a exceção para o fluxo do método, lançando pra quem o chamou(no caso o `main`), por isso não foi necessário.

Comment: @RafaelAugusto Porque primeiro você verifica se as condições estabelecidas foram atendidas, se não foram, o método deve encerrar a execução imediatamente e não fazer mais nada.

Comment: @bigown No caso ele começa lendo o método Main(Onde estão os valores do N e P) depois passa pelo if do método power. Seria isso ?

Comment: @DiegoF este é um caso para usar exceção. Ainda que eu prefiro contratos (que o Java não tem) que só vão lançar uma exceção em último caso. Note que esta é uma exceção de erro de programação que nunca deve ser capturada. No fundo eu preferia ter um mecanismo diferente da exceção para indicar o *fail-fast* que isto deveria provocar. Nem deveria dar a chance de capturar. Obviamente que o retorno do -1 pode fazer sentido dependendo da definição do que se deseja.

Comment: @RafaelAugusto Eu poderia dizer que eu acho que é isso, mas posso ter entendido errado, tá meio esquisito

Comment: @DiegoF `-1` é uma péssima ideia: `power(-1, 3)`

Comment: @utluiz eu primeiro trataria os valores como o bigown fez, e caso fossem invalidos, retornaria -1 pro método que o chamou, já o `Math.power`, colocaria num `else`, eu não iria passar o -1 pra ele não kk

Comment: @DiegoF Acho que você não entendeu. O retorno de `power(-1, 3)` é `-1`. Portanto, um retorno `-1` é perfeitamente válido para a rotina.

Comment: @DiegoF o que ele quis dizer é que neste caso o -1 pode ser um valor válido, então você estaria usando um código de erro ambíguo.

Comment: Ah sim, confundi o power com o que faz raiz quadrada kkkk erro meu.

Comment: @DiegoF tratar erros é muito difícil, com tudo o que eu escrevi eu sei que a maioria das pessoas vão cometer erros em como fazer isto, eu vivo cometendo erros, os desenvolvedores de linguagens e *frameworks* já cometeram muito esses erros e ainda cometem. É claro que eu respondi algo simplificado, se eu fosse fazer um código que fosse além de um exercício, eu faria melhor que isso, mas ainda assim seria com uma exceção. No Java no vejo forma melhor de tratar essa situação neste caso.

Answer (score 3):

## Implementação básica

> Criar uma classe que tenha apenas um método power, que recebe 2 números e calcula o numero 1 elevado ao numero 2.

Não está claro se pode usar API pronta ou se devem ser números inteiros ou de ponto flutuante.

Supondo que a resposta seja não para os dois casos, uma solução seria:

```
int power(int n, int p) {
    int r = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
        r *= n;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Outra forma funcional (Java 8) seria:

```
int power(int n, int p) {
    return IntStream.range(0, p).reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * n);
}
```

Se, entretanto, você precisa fazer isso para valores com ponto flutuante, faça assim:

```
double power(double n, double p) {
    return Math.pow(n, p);
}
```

## Validação

> Esse processo deve conter uma exceção caso algum dos números lançados seja negativo.

### Sinalizando com valor de retorno

Uma abordagem citada em comentários seria a possibilidade de retornar um valor especial no caso de erro.

Este tipo de abordagem é muito tentadora a princípio, quando se está modelando alguma biblioteca ou API.

Isso é amplamente usado linguagens com tipagem fraca como PHP ou outras que não possuem exceções.

No caso do PHP, por exemplo, uma função pode retornar um número, um booleano ou qualquer outro valor dinamicamente. Veja o exemplo:

```php
$pos = strrpos($mystring, "b");
if ($pos === false) { ... }
```

O retorno de `strrpos` é a posição de `"b"` na string ou `false` se não encontrado. Isso faz com que seja necessário testar o retorno com `===` caso contrário `$pos == false` ou `!$pos` iria avaliar para `true` se `$pos` fosse zero, o que leva a bugs frequentes em programas.

Outro problema de usar um "valor especial" para denotar erros é supor que cada rotina tem um range de valores que nunca é usado. Nem sempre isso é possível.

Ainda outro problema é que fica muito difícil criar algum padrão para denotar o erro, já que cada rotina tem seus próprios tipos de retorno válidos.

Mais um problema é que fica tudo mais confuso porque nos casos onde mais de um tipo de erro pode ocorrer. Retornar `false`, `-1`, `queijadinha` ou `xinforímpola` não diz muito sobre o problema e você começa a depender de tabelas de erros.

## Exceções

Embora mais lentas, as exceções fornecem uma forma mais clara de denotar problemas.

Uma possibilidade é tratar argumentos negativos como ilegais usando `IllegalArgumentException`, abordagem que já é citada na resposta do @Maniero:

```
int power(int n, int p) {
    if (n < 0 || p < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argumento negativo!");
    }
    return (int) Math.pow(n, p);
}
```

Dependendo do tipo de restrição que você quer impor, também pode usar `ArithmeticException`, no caso de ser uma operação matemática inválida. Esta exceção é lançada pelo Java, por exemplo, quando ocorre uma divisão por zero. Ficaria assim:

```
int power(int n, int p) {
    if (n < 0 || p < 0) {
        throw new ArithmeticException("Argumento negativo!");
    }
    return (int) Math.pow(n, p);
}
```

## Asserções

O Java possui a palavra reservada [`assert`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html) que pode ser usada para validar pré-condições e lançar um `AssertionError` caso a condição não seja atendida.

Exemplo:

```
int power(int n, int p) {
    assert n >= 0 && p >= 0;
    return (int) Math.pow(n, p);
}
```

A desvantagem do `assert` é que tal verificação é desligada por padrão, sendo mais recomendado para uso em testes do que num programa de verdade.

Entretanto, você pode [ativar asserções](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#enable-disable) para todo o programa ou seletivamente em algumas classes. A forma mais simples é passar o parâmetro `-ea` para o Java assim:

```
java -ea ...
```

## Pré-condições

Como referência para uso mais profissional, uma API de pré-condições pode ser usada para fazer asserção dos parâmetros. Existem diferentes implementações como [Valid4j](https://github.com/valid4j/valid4j) ou Google [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PreconditionsExplained).

Em Valid4j um exemplo seria:

```
int power(int n, int p) {
    require(n, greaterThanOrEqualTo(0));
    require(p, greaterThanOrEqualTo(0));
    return (int) Math.pow(n, p);
}
```

Em Guava:

```
int power(int n, int p) {
    checkArgument(n >= 0, "Esperado n positivo, mas n = %s", n);
    checkArgument(p >= 0, "Esperado p positivo, mas p = %s", p);
    return (int) Math.pow(n, p);
}
```